# What do you call an object that "compares"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call an object that compares between two or more items?

**Context:**
I'm developing a program that will compare the market performance of two products in terms of sales, revenue, profit etc.

Comment: Yep, "comparator".  It's been a term in electronics since I was in engineering school nearly 50 years ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for identifiers used in computer programming is explicitly offtopic here.

Comment: @tchrist The question is not about names for identifiers used in computer programming. Programming is just one context in which it can be used.

Comment: @YoavKadosh Could you then please give some example of such things outside the context of computer programming?

Comment: @tchrist Anything that compares between two or more objects. For example, a tool that compares between the nutrition facts of two food items.

Comment: @YoavKadosh I have never heard of such a tool. Is this something that cooks or doctor can buy?  Could you please link to it?

Comment: @tchrist: [optical comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_comparator), [electronics comparators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator), [biological comparator systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator_system) ...

Comment: @tchrist I don't know if such a tool exist, but the point is that comparing objects is beyond the realms of computer science alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for "comparator:"

> a device for comparing something with a similar thing or with a standard measure

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparator))

Example sentence:

> I'm developing a comparator program for market performance, sales, etc., of two products.

It's not a common word, and I think you would still need to use "program" after it to make your meaning clear.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***comparator***?

M-W:

> [***comparator***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparator):
>   a device for comparing something with a similar thing or with a
>   standard measure

This term finds use in physics, chemistry, and medicine at least. I see no reason one couldn't use it to characterize a program for comparing the market performance of two products.

Another possibility is ***calculator*** in the sense of a program that calculates the value of some function based on the values of a set of input parameters. Example: [calculator.net](http://www.calculator.net) lists financial  calculators, weight loss calculators, pregnancy calculators, etc. One can use such ***calculators*** to compare the results of one scenario or option to others.

**Note**: @KatherineLockwood proposed *comparator* before I did, while I was composing my answer.

Comment: Can you think of any synonyms to this word?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Another possibility is *calculator*. You use it to calculate something and then something else, and then you compare the results, for example, your retirement income based on when you retire and perhaps other assumptions. You could think of your program as a market performance calculator. You feed in the values of certain parameters, as per your question, and calculate market performance.

Comment: And you down voted this answer because?

Answer (score 1):

Consider **screener**

> A [stock screener](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stockscreener.asp) is a tool that investors and traders can use to filter stocks based on user-defined metrics. Stock screeners are offered on many websites and trading platforms, and they allow users to select trading instruments that fit a certain profile set of criteria. For example, users are able to screen for stocks by data including price, market capitalization, P/E ratio, dividend yield and 52-week price change percentage, average volume and average five-year return on investment (ROI). *source: Investopedia*